# How to Change AMcharts Label Positions?

Tags: charts, label, amcharts

I'm using AMcharts and I want to have labels horizontally aligned center of each row like the image below:

[Result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IokLj.jpg)

here's how it look's now :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAC1l.png)

The problem is that the labels seems not to be html tags and the source is using `<g></g>`, `<text></text>` and `<tspan></tspan>` tags so I can't use CSS. I also tried to use `display:block;` or such things but CSS doesn't work on these tags. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

AmCharts does not seem to have a native property to adjust the vertical centering of labels on the value axis (y-axis).

However, you can place labels in the between your ticks by using guides (https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide):

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  // ...
  "valueAxes": [ {

    "guides": [ {
      "value": 0,
      "toValue": 100,
      "label": "100"
    }, {
      "value": 100,
      "toValue": 200,
      "label": "200"
    }, {
       // etc ...
    } ],

    "labelsEnabled": false

  } ]
});
```

Add `labelsEnabled: false` to your value axis config to replace the original labels with your custom guide labels.